# What's this component?

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, identification

What is this component?(U6)

[image: figure1]

[Source](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/STM32/OLIMEXINO-STM32/resources/OLIMEXINO-STM32_Rev.A-schematic.pdf)

Comment: ESD protection diodes in a separate small package.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle I could guess it but it's a bit odd to me. also Russell's answer is nice.

Comment: Answer updated (informed by Nick's comment)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a transient absorber / suppressor.

The 4 diodes form a full wave bridge feeding voltage spikes from D+ and D- to the 3V3 power rails plus it has a zener diode acting as a voltage clamp  across the rails to absorb any energy which causes the rail voltage to rise.

---

A look at [NXP Semiconductors application note AAAAn10753](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10753.pdf) which Nick Alexeev provided the link to show that one part which matches that functionality exactly is NXP's PRTR5V0U2F/K Ultra low capacitance double rail-to-rail ESD protector [**Datasheet here**](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PRTR5V0U2F_PRTR5V0U2K.pdf). This is effectively an Application Note for USB2 ESD protection and the impact of protection on the USB signals - worth reading.

[image]

Comment: @Roh  Here's some further reading.  
Couple of application notes on ESD and transient voltage suppression for USB.  
[TI System-Level ESD/EMI Protection Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/sszb130b/sszb130b.pdf) (more practical).
[NXP AN10753](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10753.pdf) (more fundamental; diode array in question is featured on fig.20) .

Comment: @NickAlexeev Oh, special Thanks Nick. that was awesome.